# Refreshing EditText Fields on click of Camera button

Tags: android

I have two text fields and a button to capture image,on click of camera button it will capture image but entered text in text fields will be refreshed,
i have a method which will clear text and images(from the SD card).I have called this method in onCreate method.I dont want to clear those text fields upto capturing image,how to handle this?

Here is my code to capture image:

```
btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                String errorMessage = "Device doesn't support capturing images!";

            }

        }

    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
            Date date = new Date();

            String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(date);

            File imageDirectory = new File(ImagePath);
            if (!imageDirectory.exists()) {
                imageDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            String _path = ImagePath + imgcurTime + ".jpg";
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.close();
                out.flush();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use shared preference for this case.

Answer (score 0):

In low memory situations the android will kill the background activities. In your situation when camera activity started the background activity which starting the camera is may be destroying. And when you came back from camera it is recreated. So persist your edit text data same them in onSavedInstance() method and reassign them in the onRetoreInstance() method.

I hope this may works.